# Can't do "difference" boolean cut

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have to do a boolean "difference" cut but am unable to. When I try to initiate the cut it processes for about 2 minutes and then nothing happens. As you can see the cylinder object is complex which I think is causing this problem. This is the last step I need to complete before I send this prototype to a 3d printer.

[image: boolean cut objects]
[image: boolean cut objects2]

Comment: Are you sure that nothing happens? Because the Boolean doesn't remove the cutting object, you need to remove it if you apply the modifier, or make it transparent if you don't. If that doesn't fix your problem, please share your file

Comment: When I remove the cutting object I can see that nothing happens. Can you tell me how to share this file?

Comment: Also have you tried the 2 modes (Exact and Fast)? Upload your file and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I have tried to upload the barebones Blend file but it seems it's too large. I there another option?

Comment: You can use wetransfer, send it to yourself and share the link, is your topology very dense? It may explain why it takes so long to calculate

Comment: I supposed the project is very dense, I used 1024 while creating the cylinders before doing my cuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a long time to calculate because your topology is very dense, can't you simplify? Also, as you see if you display the face orientation, the faces of your object are flipped, it makes the boolean fail, you need to select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Your solution of pressing Shift + N worked and I've been able to do the cut. I saw when pressing Shift + N a message came up about changing normals. I've never understood normals or how this is part of the solution.

Comment: Secondly, a product on the shelf has to look smooth. Creating a cylinder at the high resolution of 1024 seems like a good move. Wouldn't setting the resolution to something like 512 make the surface look less smooth?

Comment: normals determine what is the direction of the face, does it points outside or inside, so I guess the boolean operation needs to know how the normals are oriented to work properly. As for smoothness, if you plan to 3D print, you probably need a high density, but if it's just for a picture or movie, you can use a rather low-poly cylinder and give it a Subdivision Surface to add virtual topology, and also in Object mode right click > Shade Smooth

Comment: Thirdly, how did you understand that the faces of my object were flipped by looking at it through the viewport overlays window? Was clicking "face orientation" showing the problem or was this part of the solution?

Comment: I could have just press Shift N without looking at the face normals, it was just a way to make sure and to show you how to check with a screenshot

Comment: In the past I've had similar challenges with doing boolean cuts on complex objects. Now that I understand the concept of normals I think Blender is going to be my tool of choice. Thanks for your time and expertise moonboots.